# conditional probability plot in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I am new to R, and I am trying to create a conditional probability plot, with pre-test probability on the x axis and post-test probability on the y axis. Similar to the one in the link [conditional probability plot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=conditional%20probability%20plot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI4ILB1rGAyAIVgVsaCh1xcgyP&biw=1280&bih=887#imgrc=Ax1bN3WZ4LfMBM%3A). I need to plot points for a positive test and join them together with a line, and plot points for a negative test and join the points together with a line, on the same graph.

I have the data:
Pre-test prob for negative `test <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)`
Post-test prob for negative `test <- c(0, 3, 7, 11, 17, 22, 30, 40, 53, 72, 100)`
Pre-test prob for positive `test < - c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)`
Post-test prob for positive `test <- c(0, 38, 57, 69, 77, 83, 88, 94, 95, 98, 100)`

However I am unsure how best to organise the data or of the code to produce the graph that I need! I have searched for "conditional probability plots" but haven't found anything helpful. 
Any guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks, Laura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to organise the data is inside a `data.frame`:

```
test = data.frame(Pos.pre = a, Pos.post = b, Neg.pre = c, Neg.post = d)
```

(Assuming your individual data was called `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.)

Now you can plot, e.g. positive post vs pre:

```
plot(Pos.post ~ Pos.pre, data = test, type = 'l')
```

(`type = 'l'` makes this a line plot.)

And you can add the negative results using the `lines` function, which adds data to an existing plot:

```
lines(Neg.post ~ Neg.pre, test, col = 'red')
```

Here, I’ve taken the liberty of making the second line red. Take a look at the documentation of `plot`, `lines` and `par` for many more options.

Once you have the time, I strongly urge you to learn using the [ggplot2 library](http://ggplot2.org/), which makes these kinds of plots more flexible. Case in point, with ggplot2 we could create the above plot in a single, extensible command:

```
ggplot(test) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Pos.pre, y = Pos.post)) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Neg.pre, y = Neg.post), color = 'red')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much that's great! Exactly what I wanted :)